# set pseudo class visibility to none

Tags: css

I have an up and down carat for column sorting contained in a pseudo class (::after) this checkbox, which came as part of a template. I was able to disable it, but now I am trying to get rid of it all together. I found a little bit on setting pseudo visibility to none but couldn't get the solutions to work for me, and I am far from a good CSSer. 
I need the column sorter for a couple of other columns so I cannot delete it entirely.

Here is my source code:

```
<th width="10%" class="sorting_asc_disabled sorting_desc_disabled sorting_asc"      
    tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-basic-markerpage" rowspan="1" colspan="1" 
    style="width: 16px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="
     : activate to sort column ascending">

       <input type="checkbox" id="checkall"></th>
        ::after
```

and here is what is contained in the ::after  :

```
media="screen"
.table-sorting .sorting_desc:after, .table-sorting .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
content: '\f0dd';
}
```

Sincere thanks for any help!

EDIT: 
Here is what worked:

```
 .sorting_desc_disabled:after{
    content: ''!important;
}
.sorting_asc_disabled:after{
        content: ''!important;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you remove those css from stylesheet if it is not required anywhere?

Comment: If its a 3rd party plugin it may be best to override the rule, as an subsequent upgrade of the plugin could restore it. Depends on the environment though I guess

Comment: Hey, sorry, forgot to add that I need the carat for some columns, just not that one. I will change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to diagnose with the provided code a solution which will work absolutely, why not set:

`content:''`

With no content, the caret will not show.

Alternatively, `display:none` should work so if it isnt, it indicates another rule with higher specificity is present or a conflict. Typically you should look into this as your first line of investigation.

Your other options could be `visbility:hidden`, `opacity:0` or `height:0;width:0;overflow:hidden`